Why the lang attribute is not allowed for html tag?
In PHP Storm 2024.1.6 I wrote an empty HTML page:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>My Project</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

it complained I didn't add the lang attribute:


Missing required 'lang' attribute

if I click on "Insert required attribute 'lang'" it add it as usual:
<html lang="it">

then it complains again the attribute is not allowed there (where it added by itself!):


Attribute lang is not allowed here

I'm not sure why it should not be allowed there.
Here, here and in almost all HTML tutorials the lang attribute is added to the html tag.
Is there a rule that prevents putting the lang attribute in the html tag?

Do you need to use DTD XHTML 1.1 and the rest? Without that line it works fine here...

This is XHTML, not HTML. I'm changing your tag.

The editor does seem a little confused, but you should use the "xml:lang" attribute with XHTML 1.1 rather than the "lang" attribute.

@Rob actually, the tag was correct. I used the example from a library, but I didn't notice it was XHTML. The IDE behavior is not the best I guess, but the root problem is I don't need XHTML, and then the attribute is valid

did you check VS code too? check other lang iso code.
this link can help you with iso-codes :
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp
you can also type ! and enter button to have a default HTML structure in vs code or phpstorm.

The lang attribute is allowed and actually recommended on the  tag in HTML. It specifies the language of the content within the document. This attribute is crucial for accessibility, search engines, and assistive technologies because it helps in determining the appropriate language for screen readers, spell checkers, and other tools that process the content.
If you're encountering a situation where the lang attribute is flagged as not allowed on the  tag, it could be due to a misunderstanding or an issue with a particular validator or tool you're using. In standard HTML 5, using the lang attribute on the  tag is correct and encouraged.
